# Shell Script to parse log and Convert to csv

Tags: shell, csv, sh

I need a shell script to parse a log file and look for a certain pattern. if that paatern found, then take key values from that line and put it into a csv. 
Example:
Here is the log file i have :

```
*webauthRedirect: Mar 24 08:57:50.903: #EMWEB-6-PARSE_ERROR: webauth_redirect.c:1034 parser exited. client mac= a0:88:b4:d3:55:8c bytes parsed = 0 and bytes read = 213
*webauthRedirect: Mar 24 08:57:50.903: #EMWEB-6-HTTP_REQ_BEGIN_ERR: http_parser.c:579 http request should begin with a character
***ewmwebWebauth1: Mar 04 11:33:46.870: #PEM-6-GUESTIN: pem_api.c:7851 Guest user logged in with user account (mrathi_dev) MAC address 00:1e:65:39:10:8e, IP address 192.168.133.146.**
*ewmwebWebauth1: Mar 04 11:33:46.870: #AAA-5-AAA_AUTH_NETWORK_USER: aaa.c:2178 Authentication succeeded for network user 'mrathi_dev'
*ewmwebWebauth1: Mar 04 11:33:46.858: #APF-6-USER_NAME_CREATED: apf_ms.c:6532 Username entry (mrathi_dev) with length (10) created for mobile 00:1e:65:39:10:8e 
*mmListen: Mar 24 08:57:49.030: #APF-6-RADIUS_OVERRIDE_DISABLED: apf_ms_radius_override.c:1085 Radius overrides disabled, ignoring source 4 
*webauthRedirect: Mar 24 08:57:47.008: #EMWEB-6-PARSE_ERROR: webauth_redirect.c:1034 parser exited. client mac= 5c:a:5b:60:f1:a7 bytes parsed = 0 and bytes read = 440
*webauthRedirect: Mar 24 08:57:47.008: #EMWEB-6-HTTP_REQ_BEGIN_ERR: http_parser.c:579 http request should begin with a character
*webauthRedirect: Mar 24 08:57:45.453: #EMWEB-6-PARSE_ERROR: webauth_redirect.c:1034 parser exited. client mac= 5c:a:5b:60:f1:a7 bytes parsed = 0 and bytes read = 440
*webauthRedirect: Mar 24 08:57:45.453: #EMWEB-6-HTTP_REQ_BEGIN_ERR: http_parser.c:579 http request should begin with a character
```

All I am interested in is the `#PEM-6-GUESTIN` line. I need to take the user id , mac and IP address from this line and put it in a csv. Only log lines with that status are required.

This is my first time working with shell scripts and all your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check `man grep` and some examples you can find in this site.

Comment: If you're not willing to put in an effort the first time chances are that you never will.

Comment: @fedorqui : thanks for editing the question. I am looking at the man pages.

Comment: @devnull : I am not looking for a freebie here, if that's what you are getting at.

Comment: Use `grep` to find the lines that you are interested in. Then if the `#PEM-6-GUESTIN` line follows a standard format, you can use `awk`, `sed` or `cut` to extract the fields which are of interest

Comment: @JoshJolly Better yet, just use `awk`... It can do the pattern matching, eliminating the need for `grep`, and then it can do whatever you need to with the specific fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is easier using `grep` to filter + `sed` to get groups using regex:

```
grep "#PEM-6-GUESTIN" log.txt | sed -r "s/.*user account \((.*)\).* MAC address (.*), IP address (.*)\.\*\*.*/\1,\2,\3/"
```

And the output is in CSV format:

```
mrathi_dev,00:1e:65:39:10:8e,192.168.133.146
```

Comment: Don't need grep here: `sed -rn '/#PEM-6-GUESTIN/{s/.../.../p}'` -- sed can do the filtering.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks glenn for the optimization ;-)